# Automated ETL / Database Migration Solution

Tags: mysql, linux, automation, etl

I'm looking for an ETL solution that we can create a configure by hand and then deploy to run autonomously. This is basic transformation, it need not be feature heavy. Key points would be *free* or *open source*'ed software that could be tailored more to suit specific needs.

In fact, this could be reduced to a simple DB migration tool that will run on a Linux server. Essentially the same as the above but we probably won't need to validate / transform the data at all besides renaming columns.

I forgot to mention that this is going to have to be very cross platform. I'd like to be able to deploy it to a server, as well as test it on OSX and Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Try Pentaho or Talend. Pentaho has a nice job-scheduling paradigm as well as the ETL workbench (Kettle). I haven't used Talend, but I've heard good things and I imagine it carries similar functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is going to have to be very cross platform. I'd like to be able to deploy it to a server, as well as test it on OSX and Windows.

Comment: Pentaho is Java-based. I do my development on OSX and have done demos etc. on Windows.